# why does my models disapper when im in edit mode?

Tags: edit-mode

Whenever I am in edit mode and I use the middle mouse button to navigate, all my meshes disappear and I cant get them back? I tried scrolling in and out but nothing would work. Help[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zptw.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Is it happening to all files or for the specific file.

Comment: Welcome, Bros Inc. Send the file for better analysis. Just use this link: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1):

there are at least a couple of ways

- select the item in the **Outliner** and then in the **View** option, under the **Align View** tab select **View selected**
- in the same menu select Center Cursor and View all or press Shift + C (it will fit all of your object on the screen)

[image]

Comment: The Home keyboard button could be a great help too.

Comment: you are right! I always forget since I have a small mac keyboard. is something not natural FN + LEFT ARROW

Comment: Nope, Im sorry I tested it when I select all and click scrollwhell on my mouse to navigate it is all gone?!